# Convert this loss function equation into python code

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, equation-solving, hinge-loss

Please check this equation of this link and convert it into a python loss function for a simple keras model.

[EQUATION PICTURE OR IMAGE LINK FOR CONVERTING IT TO PYTHON'S KERAS REQUIRED LOSS EQUATION](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16pet3eKzw-1XSh7-42M-zq7iXfl4HCfk/view?usp=drivesdk)

where the max part or the curve selected part of the equation in the picture is the hinge loss, yi represents the label of each
example, φ(x) denotes feature representation, b is a bias, k is the total number of training examples and w is the classifier to be learned.

For easy check, the sample equation is -

```
min(w) [
1/k(sum of i to k)
max(0, 1 - y_i(w.φ(x) - b))
]
+
1/2||w||^ 2 
.
```

Actually I can find the max part or the curved section of the equation in the picture but I can not find the 1/2 * ||**w**||^ 2 part.

You check this link too for help -

[similar link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782586/how-do-you-minimize-hinge-loss)

Here I have attached some sample code to clear the concept of my issue:

```
print("Create Model")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,     
input_dim=4096, init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=l2(0.001),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(32, init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(1, init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=l2(0.001),activation='sigmoid'))

adagrad=Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=1e-08)     
model.compile(loss= required_loss_function, optimizer=adagrad)

def required_loss_function(y_true, y_pred): 
      IN THIS LOSS FUNCTION, 
      CONVERT THE EQUATION IN THE 
      PICTURE INTO PYTHON CODE.
```

AS A MENTION, THE THING YOU HAVE TO FIND IS THE- 1/2 * ||**w**|| ^ 2 .
As I can find the python code of the remaining or other part of the equation in the linked picture. The hinge loss part can be easily calculated using this equation -

```
import keras

keras.losses.hinge(y_true, y_pred)
```

If you require further help, please comment for details.

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code you've managed to produce so far, and point out how and where it's failing, that would help the stackoverflow community to help you in removing your specific roadblocks.

Comment: If you are looking for hinge-loss, you can try looking at this link for python code - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L2179

Comment: @jez please check my new update and help me is solving the 1/2 * ||w||^ 2 part of the equation.

Comment: @Sampath please check my new update and help me is solving the 1/2 * ||w||^ 2 part of the equation.

Comment: You already have part of the loss, the W_regularizer=l2(0.001) part adds a term in the loss, basically lambda * ||w||^2 for that layer, so you just need to set lambda to one.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Hi Matias Valdenegro, I yet can not properly understand what you want to say, so can you please send your answer in python code form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the whole *objective function*, but only the `sum(max(...))` term is called the *loss* term.  Therefore, only that term needs to get implemented in `required_loss_function`. Indeed, you can probably use the pre-baked hinge loss from the keras library rather than writing it yourself—unless you're supposed to write it yourself as part of the exercise, of course.

The other term, the 0.5*||w||^2 term, is a *regularization* term. Specifically, it's an L2 regularization term. keras has a completely separate way of dealing with regularization, which you can read about at https://keras.io/regularizers/ .  Basically it amounts to creating an `l2` instance `keras.regularizers.l2(lambdaParameter)` and attaching it to your model with the `.add()` method (your screenshotted equation doesn't have a parameter that scales the regularization term–so, if that's literally what you're supposed to implement, it means your `lambdaParameter` would be 1.0).

But the listing you supply already seems to be applying `l2` regularizers like this, multiple times in different contexts (I'm not familiar with keras at all so I don't really know what's going on–I guess it's a more sophisticated model than the one represented in your screenshot).

Either way, the answer to your question is that the regularization term is handled separately and does *not* belong in the loss function (the signature of the loss function gives us that hint too: there's no `w` argument passed into it—only `y_true` and `y_pred`).